# Problem with .DLL and Audio Library

Tags: c#, dll, audio, embed

I have a problem with different sound libraries...
I use Visual Studio.NET and C#

I have programmed a small simulator with ebedded sound and want to have a audio library which also has pause and volume control. So I tried SDL.NET and IrrKlang. Both are working, but I want to have the simulator as a "standalone" simulator so I have to embed the audio libraries to the simulator. I tried the testversion of smartassembly, but the SDL.NET library isn't fully integrated and with Irrklang, smartassembly said that there is nonmanaged code in the irrklang library and it aborts.

So I have multiple questions:

-Is there a simple audiolibrary which I can embed easily?
-Is there a, for example, .cs-file of an audio library so I don't have to embed a .dll?
-Can I change a .dll so I have mangaged code?

Thx

EDIT:

Errormessages with SmartAssembly:
SDL.NET:

Tao.NET.dll and SDLdotNET.dll can be embedded, but SDL.NET (The Core) is not a valid .COM-Library so it can't be embedded

IrrKlang:

-IrrLang.dll can be embedded, but after converting the program says that there is "non-managed" code in library so it can't be embedded.

What can I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it finally to work :)

I used the irrklang.dll but I had chosen the "Depencies Merging"-Option in {smartassembly} instead of the "Depencies EMBEDDING"-Option

Now it works perfectly :)

Thx Pierre that you wanted to help me :)

Wonderwhy

Answer (score 1):

Try nAudio: http://naudio.codeplex.com/, you will have full source code.

But that's a library like others.

Or maybe try to edit your question and add error messages you get